# Module to dynamically generate controller concerns

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I'm rebuilding a Rails project from when I started developing, and I wanted to figure out how to really DRY my controllers out—without making them unreadable by doing half/all of the work in a `before_action`. (I've used CanCanCan's `load_resource` in the past, and it's a little too DRY for me.)

So I wrote this module to encapsulate the business logic of finding the record and loading the params data within an `Accessor` object. It's not meant to cover all cases, but right now it feels pretty robust for standard usage. I'm pretty happy with it.

I think I may blog about it, so I thought I'd post it here to see if anyone wants to point out obvious flaws or easy improvements.

Here's the module:

```
# app/controllers/concerns/resourceable.rb

require "resourceable/accessor"

# Module to DRY controllers by encapsulating finding/initializing ActiveRecord
# resources and assigning params data in a PORO. ::access_resource is called at
# the top of the controller for every resource you want to access, and two
# memo-ized getter methods are metaprogramatically defined for each. When
# called, they generate an Accessor object that returns the correct object,
# loaded with the params, but not saved.
module Resourceable

  private

  def access_resource(*models, **options)
    # Accepts a list of ActiveRecord models as symbols, strings, or constants.
    # Can also accept a single model and the following keyword options:
    #
    # key:
    #   The db column to use for finding the resource in this context.
    # columns:
    #   The columns you want to permit access to in this context.
    #   When the resource is loaded, data for these columns will be
    #   automatically assigned using strong params
    #
    # Examples:
    #   access_resources :users, :accounts
    #   access_resource Profile, key: :user_id, columns: [:username, :picture]
    #
    define_access_methods_for models.pop, options if options.present?

    models.each { |model| define_access_methods_for model }
  end

  alias access_resources access_resource

  def define_access_methods_for(resource, options = {})
    resource = resource.to_s.underscore.singularize

    define_memoized_getter_for_collection resource, options
    define_memoized_getter_for_single_record resource, options
  end

  def define_memoized_getter_for_collection(resource, options = {})
    # resource & options will be hard-coded into the method
    # params will get called when the methods is called
    define_method resource.pluralize.to_sym do
      instance_variable_get("@#{resource.pluralize}") || begin
        accessor = Accessor.new(resource, options, params)
        instance_variable_set "@#{resource.pluralize}", accessor.collection
      end
    end
  end

  def define_memoized_getter_for_single_record(resource, options = {})
    # resource & options will be hard-coded into the method
    # params will get called when the methods is called
    define_method resource.to_sym do
      instance_variable_get("@#{resource}") || begin
        accessor = Accessor.new(resource, options, params)
        instance_variable_set "@#{resource}", accessor.load_resource
      end
    end
  end

end
```

```
# app/controllers/concerns/resourceable/accessor.rb

module Resourceable
  # PORO to encapsulate the business logic of finding/initializing ActiveRecord
  # objects and loading data from params. Returned records are not saved.
  class Accessor
    attr_reader :resource, :permitted_columns

    def initialize(resource, options, params)
      @resource = resource.to_s.underscore.singularize
      @klass = resource.camelize.constantize
      @key = options[:key]
      @permitted_columns = options[:columns]
      @params = params
    end

    def collection
      klass.all
    end

    def load_resource
      record = klass.find_or_initialize_by(identifier)
      if params[resource].present?
        record.assign_attributes association_params
        record.assign_attributes resource_params
      end
      record
    end

    private

    attr_reader :key, :klass, :params

    def identifier
      key ? { key => params[key] } : { id: resource_id_from_params }
    end

    def resource_id_from_params
      params["#{resource}_id"] || (params[:id] if eponymous_controller?) || nil
    end

    def eponymous_controller?
      params[:controller] == resource.pluralize
    end

    def association_params
      params.require(resource).permit(associations)
    end

    def associations
      (klass.column_names - [key.to_s]).select do |column|
        column.end_with? "_id"
      end
    end

    def resource_params
      params.require(resource).permit(permitted_columns)
    end

  end
end
```

You add the module to your controllers:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  extend Resourceable
end
```

And then (along with the `responders` gem), your controllers look like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  access_resource :users, columns: [:email, :password, :password_confirmation]

  def index
    users
  end

  def show
    user
  end

  def new
    user
  end

  def method_name
    user.save
    respond_with user
  end

end
```

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  access_resource :profile, key: :user_id, columns: [
    :username, :picture, :gender, :birthday, :location
  ]

  def edit
    profile
  end

  def update
    profile.save
    respond_with profile, location: -> { user_path(profile.user) }
  end

end
```

I have it working in a scaffolded app [here](https://github.com/philliplongman/resourcable-test).

Comment: Doesn't `find_or_initialize_by` do a SQL query regardless, so for the `create` it will hit the database before loading the attributes. I would check if the `id` attribute is present and based on that choose to either ftech the record or just initialize its attributes.

Comment: Well, Accessors don't save anything to the db—that's reserved for the controllers. So on a `create`, it will hit the db to see if a record already exists for `{ id: nil }`, it won't find one, and it will initialize one to load the attributes into. I just looked briefly into bypassing that query when there's no primary_key value in the params. But it's going to get complicated quickly, because singular resources like `Profile` are going to be searching by their foreign_key, which will always be present.

Comment: Any query on the db, even for `id:nil` is not at all cheap. I would avoid it. Under what conditions would a foreign key be present without a desire to query the db?

Comment: For a nested singular resource like Profile, which must be found by user_id, because the routes will never contain its own id. Even on a `new` action the params will always contain a non-nil user_id. It's certainly solvable, it just adds complexity.

Comment: I see. I assume the CanCan helpers check the verb to do this.